# UML standards guide / Best Practices

Tags: uml, standards

Does anyone know of a decent UML standards guide?

My company currently relies on UML 2.0 (rightly or wrongly) to do the majority (read *all*) of their design work. I have been asked to come up with a draft 'best practice' guide to help other developers develop better models. The main problem I face is that Im slightly biased against UML... I feel that: if a diagram takes more than 5 mins to draw then its too complicated! Im looking for advice predominantly on what sort of standards I should be looking at. Also Im looking for an external source of information that can be used to balence out my irrational loathing of UML-heavy design and act as a 'sanitizer' for my suggestions.

Most of all Im looking to write a useful document rather than one that will sit moulding away in some obscure network directory.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[UML Distilled](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321193687) by Martin Fowler

Comment: I have voted up your comment, but would caution that there may be more to the question.  I have posted a comment recommending UML Profiles as it addresses the standards and usability concerns.  Fowler will help you initially, but more diagram standardization for a large group is needed.

Answer (score 3):

Like [Paul C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244457/uml-standards-guide-best-practices#244537), I recommend [UML Distilled](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321193687). It is primarily about UML, but it contains a lot of insight about design in general (although it insists a bit too much on index cards IMO), it is short, pleasant to read, and to the point.

I strongly recommend **against** [UML in a Nutshell](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565924482/). It is the worst O'Reilly book I have: insanely dense, hard to read and meandering. Not worth the paper it is printed on.

Answer (score 2):

We are not talking about a book that says how to use UML, but rather a style or standards guide of some sort.  Enter, UML profiles...  This can get you both the standardization and reduced complexity you are looking for.  You can limit the relationships and elements which can be used.  You can also require certain things.  A large company may choose to focus on the assets and data movement and limit it's standardized diagrams to this view.  However, a company making real-time software for tanks might focus on action or flow.

The whole point of UML is that it is not specific and useful for every kind of situation.  Martin Fowler and Elements of style books will not reduce diagramming time and increase comprehension.  You need standardized profiles or patterns for than.  I have seen it work, to the point that the business can read them.  Many tools allow you to create a profile which eases learning curve for the designers and reduces drawing time.

MDA Distilled (OMG Press) is a good book if you want to understand the concepts, but it is not needed.

Really, UML Profiles.  You don't want a standard because your company or your need is different.  A standard for Web Services does not work for real-time or financial services.

Comment: Ok, this got me thinking.  http://modelarchitecture.blogspot.com/2008/11/profiles-uml-problem-solver.html  Profiles will help solve your problems.

Answer (score 1):

Buy everyone a copy of [The Elements of UML 2.0 Style](http://www.ambysoft.com/books/elementsUMLStyle.html). Job done.

Comment: This really is a very good book with lots of common sense advice (#1. Avoid crossing lines) and as a bonus, it fits in your pocket!

Comment: I feel that Martin Fowler is more appropriate and that UML Style does not provide the overarching non diagrammatic advice required.  This is not just drawing, but helping people communicate.  Martin Fowler addresses this.

Answer (score 1):

For a quick reference on how to compose individual UML diagrams, I heartily recommend [The Elements of UML Style 2.0](http://www.ambysoft.com/books/elementsUMLStyle.html) and I put my money where my recommendation lies by purchasing the 2nd edition to replace my 1st ed.

Apart from this recommendation, I think the most important thing in a company when introducing any style guide is to have a **local feedback mechanism** where people can post comments on which aspects of the style guide work for them, especially when you're using an *official* printed guide. A wiki or similar casual repository should suffice for this.

I also suggest highlighting diagrams which were particularly good examples (or bad ones, if the team humor could take it). Consider a framed *Diagram of the Week* like the *Employee of the Week* you see in so many stores. That gives a gentle reminder that diagram readability is taken seriously but hopefully with enough fun to get more buy-in to the concept.

Answer (score 0):

I know you probably want an easy to read book for this but from what you are describing I would suggest going with the specs found on [OMG](http://www.uml.org/) itself. They are a bit much to read but would be as complete as you could hope for. They also have lonks to articles and tutorials that may be helpful.

As far as books go I have found that [Using UML](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321269675) is quite good since it tackles the software development process as well as the UML tools and methods.